# connectionString, i need to use password, but i'm using windows connection

Tags: c#, sql

I have created a database with visual studio, i'm using windows authentication to connect to it.

I've tried many things but it's not working

```
namespace Stock
{
    public partial class Fm_principal : Form
    {
        public SqlConnection connexion_BDD()
        {
            //Connection base de donnée
            string connectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Database;Trusted_Connection=false";

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return connection;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                return connection;
            }
        }
        public Fm_principal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void cb_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connexion_BDD();
            string request = "SELECT ref_pdt FROM produits";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(request, connexion_BDD());
            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                cb_test.Items.Add(dataReader["ref_pdt"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have an error on dataReader because the connection is currently closed

Comment: _Trusted_Connection_ should be true if you want to connect to your database using your windows account

Comment: Also look out for you calling connection_BDD(). You are returning a connection (and ignoring it once, then using it for the command) You will want a using (var connection = connection_Bdd()) { // all your code using it goes here }. And the same for SqlCommand and SqlDataReader (those are all IDisposable)

Answer (score 0):

I literally just banged this out, but you will want something like this: (Hint: Take a look at something like Dapper as you may like that better)

```
public partial class Fm_principal : Form
{
    public SqlConnection connexion_BDD()
    {
        //Connection base de donnée
        string connectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Database;Trusted_Connection=true";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return connection;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            return connection;
        }
    }
    public Fm_principal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void cb_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var connection = connection_BDD())
        {
            string request = "SELECT ref_pdt FROM produits";
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(request, connection))
            {
                using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        cb_test.Items.Add(dataReader["ref_pdt"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Just in case I am misreading your question to mean that you really want to be connecting using a username and password, then make the connection string this:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Database;User Id=YOURUSERNAME;Password=YOURPASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=false";
```

Edit: To setup SQL credentials (I do not really recommend this as I think integrated security is better as it avoids username/password credentials leaking into source control):

1. Make sure SQL Server Authentication is enabled (SSMS -> Server
   (Right-Click) -> Properties -> Security (Make sure the second radio
   button is selected "SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode"
2. You will need a server login and mapped DB user. Under the server
   (in SSMS), expand Security -> Logins. Add a login (Right-click login
   choose Add Login).
3. Enter the login name you want (this is the
   User Id in the connection string) and select SQL Server
   Authentication, then pick a (hopefully good) password. If this is a
   local box and you don't care turn off the password policy
   checkboxes.
4. In the dialog under Database Roles leave public or
   make it more privileged if you want it to manage DBs. If this is a
   local devbox making the account sysadmin can be OK.
5. In the dialog under User Mapping, select your DB and select appropriate
   roles. If the user just needs to access (read/write) data, pick
   db_datareader/db_datawriter. Often on a dev box just picking
   db_owner is best (if you are managing schema, etc.)

Comment: thank for your answer but i don't set a username and password at my databse. How i can do ? (i have created my databse with visual studio not with sql server

Comment: I will edit the answer with some details as it gets a bit long-ish.